# Registering a dll on 64 bit Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2 IIS 7

Tags: windows, dll, com

Project: VS2010 C# Class Library.
Local machine: Win 7 64bit

Following items changed in the project:

Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

Project/Properties/Build tab:
Register Com for Interop: checked
Generate Seralization assembly: auto

I have setup the test classes per following post with interfaces, comvisible=true and guids etc:
[Building a COM interop library for ASP Classic using 4.0 framework and Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923350/building-com-interop-library-for-asp-classic-using-4-0-framework-vs2010)

I was able to register this dll on my local machine via regasm. 
C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319>regasm NrccuaComFileSystem.dll

Types registered successfully.

On the server regsvr, regasm, regasm with tlb all fail with the following message:

RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\Windows\Micr
osoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\NrccuaComFileSystem.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

What am i doing wrong here?

Is it looking for an entry point, if yes then totally lost as how to provide that.

Looked at the following post also...
[Classic ASP using COM+ .Net Interop 64 Bit Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 Server.CreateObject Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281052/classic-asp-using-com-net-interop-64-bit-windows-server-2008-iis-7-server-crea)

You can download the test project from here:
http://bit.ly/wt5iJz

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working now. Following post helped.

[Classic ASP using COM+ .Net Interop 64 Bit Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 Server.CreateObject Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281052/classic-asp-using-com-net-interop-64-bit-windows-server-2008-iis-7-server-crea)

We needed to install the windows sdk for .net framework 4

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=8279

Then we needed to add the assembly to the GAC

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>gacutil /i C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\File.dll

Then we needed to register the assembly with regasm

regasm /tlb File.dll