# JScript Classic ASP "Automation server can't create object"

Tags: asp-classic

I have a DLL registered on 3 different servers, one development and two production. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381707/registering-a-dll-on-64-bit-windows-server-2008-standard-sp2-iis-7) post helped registering it on the servers.

No we are trying to put the site on a second production server so that we can load balance it. On development and one of the production servers, i can create my object and utilize it just fine. On the second production server, it gives me:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a01ad'
>   Automation server can't create object
>   /code/FileSystem.asp, line 459

Line 459 in this case is:

```
var oFSO = Server.CreateObject("Hydro.Comm.FileSystem");
```

Both production servers are Windows Server 2008 with latest patches installed. I am confused as to why the second server is not registering this DLL properly.

We followed the following steps to register the DLL on each server:

- We needed to install the windows sdk for .net framework 4
  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=8279
- Then we needed to add the assembly to the GAC:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>gacutil /i 
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\HydroComFileSystem.dll
  ```
- Then we needed to register the assembly with regasm:

  ```
  regasm /tlb HydroComFileSystem.dll
  ```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had to configure the app pool to allow 32-bit applications