# How to call a C# dll in QT Creator?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, dll

I have QT Creator latest version which works with the MS Visual studio 2010 compiler. My OS is windows 7 ultimate 32 bit. Now, the question.

I have a dll created with C#. This DLL got only `void` methods, which I need to call inside my C++ code. How can I load this DLL into QT Creator, and call the methods?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to create a COM object, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360160/how-do-i-create-an-activex-com-in-c)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: Thanks for the reply. But that is creating COM in C# right? Not from C#

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The answers to the linked question show you how to expose a C# class library as a COM object which you can register on your system. Then you can use the COM object from C++, VB, C#, Java, Javascript, PHP or whatever :)