# Seeking simple way to create a COM DLL (Active X)

Tags: com, ide, activex

The last time I did this, I used Visual Basic 6 - to which I no longer have access.

I just chose Project/New/Active X DLL and wrote a few lines of code (it was an extremely simple DLL).

Now I need to create another, also extremely simple, and am having problems since I don't have VB6 any more. I just don't understand all this GUID stuff, clas libraries, etc.

I don't care which language, but can someone recommend an IDE where I can simply create a new project and code a few lines (a function to open a serial port, read, close the port & return what was read) - without having to worry about GUIDs & Class Libraries & the like?

Thanks in advance

---

[Update] Thanks @HansPassant The DLL will be used in a legacy project.

The user goes to a web site (using MS IE **only**) and logs in. He is then prompted to scan an RFID tag. Some JS on the web page calls into the DLL which gets the RFID tag number from a reader on the serial port.

Now I want to attach a reader by USB, hence the need for a new (and simple DLL). But what's the simplest way to make it a COM DLL?

Comment: Time has not been kind to ActiveX.  You don't just need an ActiveX control, you also need a host to run it in.  Which is the part that's missing in your question.  Spinning one with a Winforms UserControl is still pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Based on your update, this looks very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3362624/1768303