# How to create an ActiveX-control in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, com, activex

I want to create an ActiveX control in C# that appears  in the toolbox selection dialog in visual studio (or other applications that are accepting ActiveX controls, like Dynamics AX):

[image: Toolbox selection dialog in VS]

I am able to create and register COM components as shown in the usual tutorials ([How do I Create an ActiveX (COM) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360160/how-do-i-create-an-activex-com-in-c)). I can create instances of my COM component in a test application using `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID`- so I know that the component registration was successfull and the component is working.

But the component is not showing up the toolbox selection dialog. Is there something special I must do with my component (code signing, implement some interfaces...)?

Comment: That Q+A is rather poor, it does not actually talk about an ActiveX control.  Just a COM component *without* a visual representation at runtime.  An extra registry entry is required to get a control to show up in a browse dialog like this one, it must have the "Control" key in its CLSID key.  And of course it must actually be a control, derived from the Winforms Control class.  And it should not be written in a .NET language if you want it to show up in this particular dialog, you always use the control directly by simply adding a reference to the assembly.

Comment: How to use managed controls as activeX control is explaine here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/24/using-managed-controls-as-activex-controls.aspx (but how various apps gather what controls to show depend on these apps...)